# Flink: How to only process specific key in window function in sliding window

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a flink job that process `Metric(name, type, timestamp, value)` Object. Metrics are keyby (name, type, timestamp). I am trying to process metrics with specific `timestamp` starting `timestamp + 50 second`. Every timestamp has interval of 10 second. I am currently trying `window(SlidingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(50), Time.seconds(10)))` with a `ProcessWindowFunction` with

```
 @Override
 public void process(Tuple3<String, Integer, Long> key, Context context, Iterable<Metric> input, Collector<Metric> collector) {
  long windowStartTime = context.window().getStart();
  long timestamp = key.f2;
  if (windowStartTime <= timestamp < windowStartTime + 10second) {
     collector.out(input.iterator().next()). //to some reducer
}
```

However, I can only get first wave of output and stop receiving things after. I also tried adding a `isProcessed` field in Metric and marked in the reducer function and apply a Evictor but doesn't seem to work.

The source and sink are kafka consumer and producer. I also have watermark setup

```
.assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(
            new BoundedOutOfOrdernessTimestampExtractor<Metric>(Time.seconds(50)) {
              @Override
              public long extractTimestamp(Metric metrics) {
                return metrics.getTimestamp() * 1000; // to millisecond
              }
            })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you are not getting more events in each window is that you have included the timestamp in the key. This has the effect of forcing each window to only include events that all have the same timestamp.

Comment: Thank you so much! that makes lot more sense. What would you suggest to use if I only want to aggregate metric with same (name, type, timestamp)? should i use TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(10)) instead of sliding window? all timestamp have 10 second interval. Thank you!!!